# How do I represent an integer in binary so I can compare using XOR?

Tags: c++, binary, xor, bit, parity

I have to create a code that takes 1-6 bits of binary, stuffs the most significant bits with 0 if the string isn't 6 already and compare 2 packets of 3 bits using the XOR operation. The outputs are weird, I think its because I'm comparing the integer 0, and not the binary number 0 when doing the XOR and it's messing up.

```
char binary[300];

cin >> binary;

int size = strlen(binary);
//cout << "Size: " << size << endl;

int a,b,c,d,e,f;

if(size == 1){
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    d = 0;
    e = 0;
    f = binary[0];

    cout << a^d << b^e << c^f << endl;
    return 0;
}

if(size == 2){
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    d = 0;
    e = binary[0];
    f = binary[1];

    cout << a^d << b^e << c^f << endl;
    return 0;
}

if (size == 3){
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
    d = binary[0];
    e = binary[1];
    f = binary[2];

    cout << a^d << b^e << c^f << endl;
    return 0;
}

if (size == 4){
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = binary[0];
    d = binary[1];
    e = binary[2];
    f = binary[3];

    cout << a^d << b^e << c^f << endl;
    return 0;
}

if (size == 5){
    a = 0;
    b = binary[0];
    c = binary[1];
    d = binary[2];
    e = binary[3];
    f = binary[4];

    cout << a^d << b^e << c^f << endl;
    return 0;
}

if (size == 6){
    a = binary[0];
    b = binary[1];
    c = binary[2];
    d = binary[3];
    e = binary[4];
    f = binary[5];

    cout << a^d << b^e << c^f << endl;
    return 0;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: This code is a mess. Start with describing more in detail what you're required to do. Eg. do you really type a binary number like 101010 as input, or a normal decimal number like 1234?

Comment: yes its just a binary number as an input

Comment: And you need to use xor to compare and print 0 for every equal digit and 1 for every non-equal digit?

Comment: Huh? There's no separate "binary number" type. Numbers do not have bases. You can write down a number in a particular base, but the number itself does not have a base.

Comment: @immibis ...or typing them with a keyboard, which is exactly what the program here wants.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the first part of the code block (was scrolled down) where `binary` is a string the user typed in.

Answer (score 0):

As your code is pretty bad, here a cleaner version.
Try to understand what's going on instead of just copying it.

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
while(s.length() < 6)
    s = "0" + s;  
std::cout << (bool)(s[0] ^ s[3]);
std::cout << (bool)(s[1] ^ s[4]);
std::cout << (bool)(s[2] ^ s[5]);
```